# Oracle: what information can I derive from the SCN?

Tags: oracle

Given an SCN (system change number), and assuming an SCN for which the data is still in the undo logs, what information about the SCN can I derive?

- of course, SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP() gives an approximate time the data was committed.
- Is there any other information I can derive?  What transaction, what tables, what data were affected? etc?

Comment: Which version? Using logminer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS - you can track back the transaction using Log Miner.

You can find which point a particular transaction happened to assist in determining a point in time to restore a database - SET UNTIL SCN =  for example.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good question for [Tom :).](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9434169398289)